# Assigned input Value is not submitted to PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an HTML form and an input whose type is file, i wanted to assign a value to the input and i did, but when the form is submitted the file will not be submitted with the assigned value.
Here is my code:

```html
<form action="card.php"method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type = "file" name = "in_img" value = "img/myimage.jpg">
</form>
```

The receiver PHP is:

```
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["in_img"]["name"]);
```

And i always see the same error as if the file was not submitted. Please help...?

Comment: `Form` must have proper `enctype` attribute.

Comment: And have `method="POST"`

Comment: I did that too.<form action="card.php"method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: What is the error you get? Could you paste the output of `var_dump($_FILES);` please? Also, you should not use `value` attribute in with `<input type="file">`

Answer (score 1):

For submit file you must have to pass enctype in it. Change you form tag to

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type = "file" name = "in_img" value = "img/myimage.jpg">
</form>
```

Comment: I did that too.. <form action="card.php"method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">